# Is there a way of export a row of buttons as a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, refactoring

I have this row on two pages, I would like to extract as a widget to avoid repetition, but my IDE doesn't let me do that showing a message bubble instead:

> Reference to an enclosing class method cannot be extracted

Below is my Row, I tried enclosing it within a Container but is the same result.

```
  child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TagButton(
                    isActive: _selectedTag == 'cart',
                    tagIcon: Icons.local_grocery_store,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedTag = 'cart';
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  TagButton(
                    isActive: _selectedTag == 'school',
                    tagIcon: Icons.school,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedTag = 'school';
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  TagButton(
                    isActive: _selectedTag == 'all',
                    tagIcon: Icons.block,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedTag = 'all';
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  TagButton(
                    isActive: _selectedTag == 'relax',
                    tagIcon: Icons.spa,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedTag = 'relax';
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  TagButton(
                    isActive: _selectedTag == 'recipes',
                    tagIcon: Icons.restaurant,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedTag = 'recipes';
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

I tried extracting it as a method but as soon as I move it to another dart file (so I can import to the two pages and use it there) a lot of warnings show up

```
lib/widgets/tagsBar.dart:17:13: Error: Method not found: 'setState'.
  setState(() {
  ^^^^^^^^
lib/widgets/tagsBar.dart:23:21: Error: Getter not found: 'selectedTag'.
  isActive: selectedTag == 'school',
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to implement as separate class `widget`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SharedWidgetRow extends StatefulWidget {
  final stateRebuild;

  SharedWidgetRow({@required this.stateRebuild});
  @override
  _SharedWidgetRowState createState() => _SharedWidgetRowState();
}

class _SharedWidgetRowState extends State<SharedWidgetRow> {
  var  _selectedTag = 'cart';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        TagButton(
          isActive: _selectedTag == 'cart',
          tagIcon: Icons.local_grocery_store,
          onTap: () {
            _selectedTag = 'cart';
            widget.stateRebuild();
          },
        ),
        TagButton(
          isActive: _selectedTag == 'school',
          tagIcon: Icons.school,
          onTap: () {
            selectedTag = 'school';
            widget.stateRebuild();
          },
        ),
        TagButton(
          isActive: _selectedTag == 'all',
          tagIcon: Icons.block,
          onTap: () {
            _selectedTag = 'all';
            widget.stateRebuild();
          },
        ),
        TagButton(
          isActive: _selectedTag == 'relax',
          tagIcon: Icons.spa,
          onTap: () {
            _selectedTag = 'relax';
            widget.stateRebuild();
          },
        ),
        TagButton(
          isActive: _selectedTag == 'recipes',
          tagIcon: Icons.restaurant,
          onTap: () {
            _selectedTag = 'recipes';
            widget.stateRebuild();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And `setState()` needs to be in same context, so you should pass it as a parameter when calling this widget

```
SharedWidgetRow(stateRebuild: setState((){})),
```

you should consider making this variable `_selectedTag` global if will be used somewhere else

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the Ide shows the following warning `error: The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore can't be used. (use_of_void_result at [notes_app] lib\screens\note_screen.dart:197)` on the file that I inserted the Custom Widget.

Another thing, on one screen `_selectedTag` is used for filtering logic, on the other is used to set a property of an object, Do you think that it makes sense making it a global variable?

Also, can you explain briefly why there is no need for `setState` of the `_selectedTag` inside the `onTap` property?